# Can I apply predicates to the same columns against multiple tables in a JOIN only once?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I want to join two tables together and add additional information from two other tables to the same columns in both queried tables. I've come up with the below code, which works, but I don't feel comfortable about having to add another `JOIN` clause for each table, as it would make the query substantially long if I wanted to join/add more things.

Is there a way to combine it, so that I can join additional tables only once (just use `S` and `E` aliases every time)?

```
SELECT
    J.JobId,
    J.StandardJobId,
    S.JobName,
    J.EngineerId,
    E.EngineerName,
    JF.JobId AS FollowUpJobId,
    JF.StandardJobId AS FollowUpStandardJobId,
    SF.JobName AS FollowUpJobName,
    JF.EngineerId AS FollowUpEngineerId,
    EF.EngineerName AS FollowUpEngineerName
FROM
    Jobs J
INNER JOIN
    Jobs JF
ON
    J.FollowUpJobId = JF.JobId
INNER JOIN
    StandardJobs S
ON
    J.StandardJobId = S.StandardJobId
INNER JOIN
    Engineers E
ON
    E.EngineerId = J.EngineerId
INNER JOIN
    StandardJobs SF
ON
    SF.StandardJobId = JF.StandardJobId
INNER JOIN
    Engineers EF
ON
    EF.EngineerId = JF.EngineerId
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to use a Common Table Expression (CTE) - something like:

```
with cte as
(SELECT J.JobId,
        J.StandardJobId,
        S.JobName,
        J.EngineerId,
        E.EngineerName,
        J.FollowUpJobId
 FROM Jobs J
 INNER JOIN StandardJobs S ON J.StandardJobId = S.StandardJobId
 INNER JOIN Engineers E ON E.EngineerId = J.EngineerId)
SELECT O.*,
       F.StandardJobId AS FollowUpStandardJobId,
       F.JobName AS FollowUpJobName,
       F.EngineerId AS FollowUpEngineerId,
       F.EngineerName AS FollowUpEngineerName
FROM CTE AS O
JOIN CTE AS F ON O.FollowUpJobId = F.JobId
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot avoid JOINing related tables each time a separate reference is needed. The issue is that you are not working with the tables in a general sense but instead working with the specific rows of each table, even more specifically, just those rows that match the JOIN and WHERE conditions.

There is no way to specify the references to either `StandardJobs` or `Engineers` only once because you are needing to work with two rows from each table *at the same time*, at least in the given example.

However, depending on which direction you are wanting to go with "additional tables" (more references to `Jobs` or more lookups like `StandardJobs` and `Engineers` for the given 2 references of `Jobs`), the CTE construct shown by Mark is the probably the easiest / best way to abstract it.  I posted this answer mainly to explain the issue at hand.

Comment: "*There is no way to specify the references to either StandardJobs or Engineers only once*"  This is not correct.  Both CTEs and Views can be used to allow the references from Jobs to StandardJobs and Engineers to be specified only once.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: I understand that about CTEs & Views which is why I edited my answer to say that the CTE-based answer given by Mark is the best way to abstract those JOINs. BUT, I was addressing the general case of the question in terms of multiple references to the same table. Using CTEs or Views in this specific case only worked because the two main references were the same table, in which case it wasn't just the lookups that were duplicated, but the entire structure. Others might have a main reference of a single table, or two different tables, in which case CTEs & Views won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort of do this with either a CTE (Common Table Expressions, the `WITH` clause) or a View:

```
;WITH Jobs_Extended As
(
    SELECT  j.*,
            s.JobName,
            E.EngineerName
    FROM    Jobs         As j
    JOIN    StandardJobs As s   ON s.StandardJobId = j.StandardJobId
    JOIN    Engineer     As e   ON e.EngineerId = j.EngineerId
)
SELECT
    J.JobId,
    J.StandardJobId,
    J.JobName,
    J.EngineerId,
    J.EngineerName,
    JF.JobId         AS FollowUpJobId,
    JF.StandardJobId AS FollowUpStandardJobId,
    JF.JobName       AS FollowUpJobName,
    JF.EngineerId    AS FollowUpEngineerId,
    JF.EngineerName  AS FollowUpEngineerName
FROM    Jobs_Extended   J
JOIN    Jobs_Extended   JF  ON  J.FollowUpJobId = JF.JobId
```

In this example the CTE `Jobs_Extended` becomes a defined alias for the relationship between the Jobs, Engineers and StandardJobs tables.  Then once defined, you can use it multiple times in the query without having to redefine those interior relations.

You can do the same thing by change the `WITH` to a View, which will make the defined alias permannet in your database.